# Can't access MySQL Docker container remotely

Tags: mysql, docker, remote-access

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` configuration:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: "mysql:8.0.23"
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=somethingsomething
    volumes:
      - /home/gutta-server/Servers/mysql/hvb_db:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    expose:
      - 3306

  adminer:
    image: "adminer:4.8.0-standalone"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 7000:8080
```

I have also opened ports 3306 and 7000 on the router that the host is connected to. Going to <my-domain>:7000 in my browser, from an external network, I am able to log in to Adminer and manage my database. I have also ran `ufw allow 3306` on the host.

It's also worth noting that running `telnet localhost 3306` on the *host* server (the one that actually runs the container) works, and confirms to me that the local port mapping is working just fine.

However, running the same command, just as `telnet <my-domain> 3306` from a remote computer, not on the same network, yields the following:

```
Trying <my-domain's-ip>...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Therefore, something must be wrong with the *remote* connection, not the actual database itself.

I feel like I've scoured SO dry, but having experience with these forums, surely someone will links this exact issue :p Anyway, here are the things I've tried:

- Port forwarding port 3306 in router configuration (I have other port forwards too, which work perfectly fine, shouldn't be a router or ISP issue)
- Allowing port 3306 though the host's firewall (`ufw allow 3306`)
- Add `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` to the container's `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file and restarting the container (`docker-compose restart` doesn't remove this entry, stopping and starting does. I would solve this with a volume if it actually solved the issue, but it didn't)
- Completely disable ufw (after suggestion in comments)

I literally can't think of a single other thing that could possibly be wrong, and I can't find anything more on the internet, either..
I really hope I've provided enough information here, please do let me know if anything else is needed.

Comment: have you tried to disable `ufw` temporary and check if it works?

Comment: @jordanvrtanoski tried it now, no difference :/

Comment: Have you tried `mysql --protocol=tcp -u root -p` on your host ? Or only telnet ?

Comment: @Faeeria I don't actually have mysql installed on the host system, I figured there was no need for that. Is that required, perhaps? If so, would I need both client and server on the host, too?

Comment: That is not required, it was just to have different results, but not necessary.